# How to see what processes WERE running?

Tags: monitoring, ps, crash

Is there a chance to get the processes that **RAN** before my system crash?

**EDIT**

What I really want is to see the past processes.
My system crashed & I want to know if a specific process was the main reason.

I search into all /var/log logs, but nothing, the only suspect in this were some apache logs, where I found some kind of scans... So now I want to check out for all processes running at that time.

Comment: Your question is not clear: Are you asking for a way to get a list of all running processes, at the time of a system crash? And what do you mean by crash, it is one of these words that can mean a different thing to each person.

Comment: @richard Why are you trying to make the question more complicated than it is? He wants to get `ps` from an earlier point in time. The part about the crash is only the reason why he wants to get the `ps`, and has nothing else to do with the question.

Answer (score 3):

Using a simple script it is possible to keep a running log of processes. With the log, you can go back and view what was running and what wasn't.

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p "$HOME/ps_logs"

while true; do
    ps aux > "$HOME/ps_logs/ps_$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S).log"
    sleep 60 # Logging interval in seconds.
done
```

Unfortunately, without a log, you cannot go back in time and retrieve a list of running processes.

Answer (score 3):

Use the crash command.

```
# crash /usr/lib/debug/lib/module/vmlinux /var/crash/vmcore
crash> ps
```

Note that you'll need to set up your system to save crash dumps.